# How to make orders as complete mannually

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status, order-state

I am shipping some orders manually and i want this orders in the magento for record purpose only.so i had placed this orders in the magento.

Now issue is i want to make this orders as complete but i dont want to create invoice and shipment.just make order as complete.

i had tried to make this order as complete programmtically but i am getting error as `The Order State "complete" must not be set manually`.

this means for order to be complete it should have to be invoiced first then shipment then only order will become complete

is their any way to make this order as complete.

Comment: I have only idea how ignore shipping. You can try for short period let magento think that your order contains only virtual items. In that shipment should not be created. For example some modules which allows create custom options for grouped products let magento think, that item is not grouped. It is simple.

Comment: ok you saying i have to use virtual products.but i have already created orders with simple products and i need to make complete

Comment: I mean that, when you are trying to complete order, you can try programmaticaly let magento think that you have virtual instead of simple products. When you try to set status complete, check which data magento validate, maybe you can say it, that your order already have unexisted shipment and invoice. I'm talking in general.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way is modifying the database directly, but I wouldn't recommend that. Thus, you'll have to create invoice and shipment programatically.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend that? Another way would be extending the Mage_Sales_Model_Order model, but just modifying the database would be easier if it's only one time.